# How do I open a .txt form terminal in Sublime Text 4?

Tags: linux, windows, terminal, command

I don't have the command `subl` because I installed mine in `D:` drive and not in `C:` (the default path for Sublime Text. Is there a file I should edit where I can change the path of this command so I can open files directly from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the system default environmental path .
Try this in a command prompt

```
sysdm.cpl
```

this will open a new tab , navigate to environmental variables tab and add new variable with the `PATH` to sublime executable

> restart the terminal